# Which is hotkey to reach end of "}" from "{"?

Tags: sublimetext2, atom-editor, adobe-brackets

I'm curious there a hotkey where you reach end of } from { of if, ifelse and else, I have a file is too long to scroll down. I need to fix syntax error.

Comment: no idea about sublime, but in VI, you can use `%` to "bounce" on that sort of thing.

Comment: @MarcB did you mean VIM? I have never used VIM.

Comment: vim = "vi improved". basically VI with a bunch of extra (useful) stuff.

Comment: @MarcB It would confuse me because It looks like a roman number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sublime ctrl+M

Ctrl + M    Jump to closing parentheses Repeat to jump to opening parentheses

http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html

Comment: I'm using atom.io and brackets.io, isn't there a shortkey to jump to closing parentheses?

Comment: Never used atom.io and brackets.io, just check link https://atom.io/packages/atom-shortcuts (folding section) if that solve your purpose.

Comment: For Atom it's also CTRL + m

Comment: try ctrl+J for brackets.io

Comment: Atom and Sublime 2 work with Ctrl+M, but Brackets.io doesn't work, which is missing feature.

I found an extension for brackets https://github.com/peterflynn/brackets-jump-to-matching it would work with Ctrl+Shift+[


@Narendra did you install some extension or some config to use ctrl+J? it doesn't work for me.